# File is used by other process

Tags: c#, count

I'm using #C. If I do

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("trades.txt");
// write a line of text to the file
tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
// close the stream
tw.Close();
```

It will get an error that the file is used by an other process:

```
[Henry 2014-11-26 21:10:45] ERROR: System.IO.IOException: Kan geen toegang krijg
en tot het bestand C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\HatBot\Bin\Debug\trades.txt omdat h
et wordt gebruikt door een ander proces.
   bij System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   bij System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions
options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boole
an useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   bij System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)

   bij SteamBot.SimpleUserHandler.OnMessage(String message, EChatEntryType type)
 in c:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\HatBot\SteamBot\SimpleUserHandler.cs:regel 160
   bij SteamBot.Bot.<HandleSteamMessage>b__9(FriendMsgCallback callback) in c:\U
sers\Jonathan\Desktop\HatBot\SteamBot\Bot.cs:regel 498
   bij SteamKit2.CallbackMsg.Handle[T](Action`1 handler)
   bij SteamBot.Bot.HandleSteamMessage(CallbackMsg msg) in c:\Users\Jonathan\Des
ktop\HatBot\SteamBot\Bot.cs:regel 488
  bij SteamBot.Bot.BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWo
rkEventArgs) in c:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\HatBot\SteamBot\Bot.cs:regel 826

[Henry 2014-11-26 21:10:45] ERROR: System.IO.IOException: Kan geen toegang krijg
en tot het bestand C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\HatBot\Bin\Debug\trades.txt omdat h
et wordt gebruikt door een ander proces.
   bij System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   bij System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions
options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boole
an useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   bij System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)

   bij SteamBot.SimpleUserHandler.OnMessage(String message, EChatEntryType type)
 in c:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\HatBot\SteamBot\SimpleUserHandler.cs:regel 160
   bij SteamBot.Bot.<HandleSteamMessage>b__9(FriendMsgCallback callback) in c:\U
sers\Jonathan\Desktop\HatBot\SteamBot\Bot.cs:regel 498
   bij SteamKit2.CallbackMsg.Handle[T](Action`1 handler)
   bij SteamBot.Bot.HandleSteamMessage(CallbackMsg msg) in c:\Users\Jonathan\Des
ktop\HatBot\SteamBot\Bot.cs:regel 488
   bij SteamBot.Bot.BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWo
rkEventArgs) in c:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\HatBot\SteamBot\Bot.cs:regel 826
```

What to do? I want with a command to count it the lines, which I got already, but this is getting errors.

Comment: have you tried issuing the `Flush()` Method prior to coding.. also is that all the code you are using..? show all relevant code as well also look at re-factoring the code to wrap your `TextWriter` around a `using`

Comment: Well, it looks like another process has locked the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is a new file you can try the following

```
string filePath = @"c:\"trades.txt"";
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{
    tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    tw.Flush();
}
```

Another way of doing this

```
using System.IO;
using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\trades.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
   fileStream.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString());
   fileStream.Flush();
}
```